# Laravel 5.3 redirect if not logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3 with Valet.

web.php

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
  Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
});
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

If I hit the `/dashboard` route **not** logged in, it throws an exception rather than redirecting me to the `/login` page.
[image: exception]

Is this the correct behaviour or am I missing something? I thought it was supposed to redirect you to the login page, no?

Comment: I just fixed compatibility issues with Laravel ^5.3 in the module you're using:
https://github.com/darkwinternight/laravel-error-handler/pull/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should redirect. A fresh install will redirect when not logged in **and** when it's not an api request.

It seems it is no longer capturing the error and instead allowing it to surface all the way to the top.

Possibly you have made changes to your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` code and is causing it to skip past handling these errors correctly.

Comment: Yes, it was because I was using [this](https://github.com/darkwinternight/laravel-error-handler) package which requires you to extend it's own handler. I've posted an issue there for the owner.

Comment: Awesome. Glad the answer got you on the right track